# Can FunctionTestCase methods take in arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm using unittest for some testing in Python. I am interested in FunctionTestCase. From the docs, this is the sample use:

```
testcase = unittest.FunctionTestCase(testSomething,
                                     setUp=makeSomethingDB,
                                     tearDown=deleteSomethingDB)
```

testSomething is defined as

```
def testSomething():
    something = makeSomething()
    assert something.name is not None
    # ...
```

However, I am interested in passing in an argument to testSomething(), like below.

```
  def testSomething(input):
        something = makeSomething(input)
        assert something.name is not None
        # ...
```

When I run it having constructed it as above:

```
runner= unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(testcase)
```

I get

```
    ERROR: unittest.case.FunctionTestCase (test_meth4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: testSomething() missing 1 required positional argument: 'input'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.007s
```

Is there a way to pass in the argument, or would I need to use something like a closure/outer function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can pass arguments to the function that is being tested. In both Python 2 and 3, `FunctionTestCase.runTest()` contains only one line: `self._testFunc()`, with no provision for passing arguments. You can subclass `FunctionTestCase` and add arguments to its `__init__()`, and then have `runTest()` pass them to the function that is being tested:

```
import unittest

def my_func(arg1, arg2=None):
    print('arg1 is', arg1)
    print('arg2 is', arg2)

class MyFunctionTestCase(unittest.FunctionTestCase):
    def __init__(self, testFunc, setUp=None, tearDown=None,
                 description=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        super(MyFunctionTestCase, self).__init__(testFunc, setUp=setUp,
                                                 tearDown=tearDown,
                                                 description=description)
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def runTest(self):
        self._testFunc(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

my_test = unittest.FunctionTestCase(my_func)
my_subclassed_test = MyFunctionTestCase(my_func, args=(42,), kwargs={'arg2': 24})

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(my_test)
runner.run(my_subclassed_test)
```

I would encourage you to request this functionality and/or more documentation on this at https://bugs.python.org. This seems like a significant gap and there is practically no official documentation for `FunctionTestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, it is not possible to provide arguments for your test function using `unittest.FunctionTestCase()`. However, you could use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a wrapper function that calls the original function with additional arguments.

Given your original example, you could do something like this:

```py
wrapped_func = functools.partial(testSomething, input)
wrapped_func()  # this is now equivalent to testSomething(input)
```

(*Note that `input` is also the name of a built-in function in Python, so I'd recommend another name for your variable.*)

A full working example based on the other answer (for easier comparison) is this:

```py
import functools
import unittest

def my_func(arg1, arg2=None):
    print('arg1 is', arg1)
    print('arg2 is', arg2)

my_wrapped_func = functools.partial(my_func, 42, arg2=24)
functools.update_wrapper(my_wrapped_func, my_func)
my_wrapped_test = unittest.FunctionTestCase(my_wrapped_func)

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(my_wrapped_test)
```

The line with `update_wrapper()` is necessary to make the wrapped function more look like the original function, which is necessary for the unittest framework to print the name of the function in case of a failure.